# Trying to run Spark Submit, Hadoop and other command line commands

Tags: powershell, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm using PowerShell to set up a test instance that is running on Windows.  When the instance is up and running it will then run a few commands to get Hadoop set up and will then run a Spark job.
This all works fine when done manually from within the instance itself.  I'm now trying to translate those commands into powershell.

These two for example are failing with the message that it is not a recognised cmdlet or function etc:

```
& $env:HADOOP_HOME + "\bin\winutils.exe" chmod 777 /tmp/hive
& $env:HADOOP_HOME + "\bin" hadoop namenode -format -force
```

The error I receive is:

> & : The term 'c:\hadoop\bin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:3

I've then tried various combinations of wrapping in quotes, using `iex`, assigning it to a variable, but all fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell interprets the expanded value of `$env:HADOOP_HOME` as the command to execute, which fails, because a folder isn't a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Do the concatenation in a subexpression:

```
& ($env:HADOOP_HOME + "\winutils.exe") chmod 777 /tmp/hive
```

or put the environment variable directly in the command string:

```
& "$env:HADOOP_HOME\winutils.exe" chmod 777 /tmp/hive
```

Comment: Hi,  Thank you for the suggestion.  I've tried both of these in the shell and they both give me the same error.  Is there perhaps something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Check your paths. Judging from your earlier error message the `bin` directory seems to be part of `$env:HADOOP_HOME`, so you should probably use `"$env:HADOOP_HOME\winutils.exe"` rather than `"$env:HADOOP_HOME\bin\winutils.exe"`.

Comment: absolutely right - as was pointed out by a colleague that needs a hug! :D  Thank you!